# Azure CLI: az cdn endpoint purge | Not working with Service Principal

Tags: azure-cli

My Service Principal has the following two roles on the whole Resource Group **Playground**

1. CDN Endpoint Contributor
2. CDN Profile Contributor

I am trying to run the following commands

```
az login --service-principal --username="ca85199a-7e86-40eb-b6c8-a774a9edc010" --password="<pwd>" --tenant="<tenant-id>"

az cdn endpoint purge -n mopar --profile-name mopar-poc --content-paths "/*" --resource-group Playgroud --no-wait
```

I am getting the following error.

```
AuthorizationFailed: The client 'acd5dfea-f69a-4178-812c-4204963c6959' with object id 'acd5dfea-f69a-4178-812c-4204963c6959' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints/purge/action' over scope '/subscriptions/b19669be-bfa2-4e86-b7d4-f1b4d98dd2a5/resourceGroups/Playgroud/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/mopar-poc/endpoints/mopar' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The two roles are enough, the command works fine on my side, please follow the steps below to troubleshoot.

1.Double-check the RBAC roles in the azure portal, make sure the correct service principal has the correct role in the correct scope.

2.Run `az account clear` first, then login again to make sure you are using the correct service principal.

3.Make sure you logged in to the correct subscription, just use `az account set --subscription <subscription-id>` after login to set it.

Comment: @AkashPavate If it is helpful, please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error was misleading.

Turns out I had misspelled Playground in the command below.

az cdn endpoint purge -n mopar --profile-name mopar-poc --content-paths "/*" --resource-group **Playgroud** --no-wait